# How is this number being represented in assembly?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I am trying to analyze assembly code for the function

```
double test_class::Operators_2_12_addtion_07(double input) {

    /*add input with constant value 5*/
      double a = input + 5;

    /*Branch unconditional return*/
    return a;

}
```

here is the assembly output for the code:

```
double test_class::Operators_2_12_addtion_07(double input) {
   0:   3d 20 00 00     lis     r9,0
   4:   c0 09 00 00     lfs     f0,0(r9)
      double a = input + 5;

    /*Branch unconditional return*/
    return a;

}
   8:   fc 21 00 2a     fadd    f1,f1,f0
   c:   4e 80 00 20     blr
```

In the code, I add a constant value of 5 to input parameter passed through function. The instruction listed in the assembly for the instruction is:

```
0:  3d 20 00 00     lis     r9,0
4:  c0 09 00 00     lfs     f0,0(r9)
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding how the value 5 is being represented in the assembly.

Comment: *Need details on code* is not a useful question title. Please [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking or what problem you're trying to solve in a way that will mean something to future readers who find it in a search result.  The *Power PC* is not necessary; that information is available in the tag you gave to your post. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you used `objdump`, make sure you pass `-r` option to see relocation entries. I guess the constant `5` has been placed into memory and it's accessed indirectly through `r9`. The two zeroes probably have relocation entries to the constant's address.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Listen to Jester's comment.

---

### Relocation

When a compiler compiles a code unit is usually assumes its code starts at address 0, so it generates object files with addresses relatives to 0 (unless [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) is generated).

When the linker links the object files it usually puts each code section one after the other, so it must "shift" the addresses of sections that come after the first.

When the program is loaded, its starting address can be [randomly chosen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), so the loaded must "shift" all the addresses one more time.

This is called [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), it can be done in various way and implies that the addresses stored in an object/binary file are usually zero or relative to zero.

### PowerPC address loading

As it is common among [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) machines, loading a register width constant (as an address is) takes two instructions.
One for the upper bits and one for the lower.
In PowerPC this is accomplished with the pair

```
lis r1, HIGH16         ;Move HIGH16<<16 into r1
ori r1, LOW16          ;r1 = HIGH16<<16 | LOW16
```

If the address is used for loading some data, the second instruction can be
"fused" into the load though the use of the displacement

```
lis r1, HIGH16         ;Move HIGH16<<16 into r1
lwz r2, LOW16(r1)      ;r2 = mem[HIGH16<<16 + LOW16]
```

### PowerPC (part of) calling convention

When [calling a function](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/elfspec_ppc.pdf) that uses floating points the convention is to put the input parameters into the registers *f1*-*f8*.
The return values is in *f1*.
*f0* is a volatile register.

### Putting all this together

There is no instruction that load a floating point immediate, so it must be located into memory.
I don't know what floating point format PowerPC uses, I assumes [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).
In that case the number 5 is represented as +1.01x2<sup>2</sup> that as [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is

```
  S  Exp (127+2)  Significand (Implicit 1)
+---+-----------+-------------------------+
| 1 | 1000 0001 | 010 0000 0000 0000 0000 |
+---+-----------+-------------------------+
```

or 40a00000h.

You can experiments with floating points [here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=053).

```
; f1 = input


;This load a float at address 0 (not yet relocated) into f0
;Such float is the literal 5.
;The zeros are actually the upper and lower part of the literal address
;(that is not relocated)
lis     r9, 0
lfs     f0, 0(r9)  

;f1 = input
;f0 = 5
fadd    f1,f1,f0

;f1 = input + 5
;f0 = 5
blr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help